# Django order by count (@property) in many-to-many?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have the following classes:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    articles = models.ManyToManyField(Article, blank=True, null=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True, null=True)


class Product(models.Model):
    @property
    def sites_count(self):
        return self.site_set.count()
```

In my admin I would like to the many to many relationships to be sorted by sites_count.

```
class SiteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "articles":
             kwargs['queryset'] = Article.objects.order_by('sites_count')
        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

I get complaints that sites_count cannot be used because it's not a column in my db.

What is an alternative approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an aggregation and order by that.

```
from django.db.models import Count
Article.objects.annotate(site_count=Count('site')).order_by('site_count')
```